# How to subtract two methods in Java?

Tags: java, variables, integer, bluej, subtraction

Noob question, but I want to calculate the goal difference, so the two methods are "Goals For" and "Goals Against". I want to subtract these two methods so that it returns a result whenever I press the getGoalDifference method. (Obviously, what I wrote in the body of the getGoalDifference method below is completely wrong, I just don't know what the exact code is)

```
public int getGoalsFor(){

    return GoalsFor;
}

public int getGoalsAgainst(){

    return GoalsAgainst;
}

public int getGoalDifference(){

    return 

     GoalsFor - GoalsAgainst; 



}
```

Comment: `GoalsFor() - GoalsAgainst();`

Comment: Hint: this is **super** basic stuff. Consider reading some good book / tutorial.

Comment: actually your code would work, assuming they are in the same class. (although it might be better to use the methods)

Comment: In java, you don't substract methods. You can call two methods and do computation with their results. You should learn basis.

Answer (score 1):

Do your `getGoalsFor()` and `getGoalsAgainst` methods work? If they work your `getGoalDifference()` should work as well. The reason is that `GoalsFor` and `GoalsAgainst` are variables in your class and it seems like you can access these two variables (since the two get methods work prefectly fine).

Though i don't know if this makes any differences, but the return statement is normally written in one line

```
public int getGoalDifference(){
    return GoalsFor - GoalsAgainst; 
}
```

instead of

```
public int getGoalDifference(){
    return 

     GoalsFor - GoalsAgainst; 
}
```

If your code still doesn't work please explain what the problem/error is.

Of course you can also write the getGoalifferences() method as following:

```
public int getGoalDifference(){
    int goalsFo = getGoalsFor();
    int goalsAg = getGoalsAgainst();
    return goalsFo - goalsAg; 
}
```

Another small info: variable names normally start with small letters `goalsFor` instead of `GoalsFor`  =)

Edit:  Also you never substract Methods in java. In some other programming languages "substracting methods" is more or less possible but not in java. What you substract are always variables (values). Even if it seems like you "substract methods" you substract the values returned by the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to compile, but your function should looks like:

```
 public int getGoalDifference(){
     return this.getGoalsFor() - this.getGoalsAgainst(); 

}
```

Comment: You don't use this. for method calls (I think it isn't even allowed)

Comment: Can be used without this of course. But this will work also. Even his sample should work if this what he returns is variable names.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
    public int getGoalDifference(){
      int goalsFor,gaolsAgainst; 
      goalsFor =  GoalsFor();
      gaolsAgainst = GoalsAgainst(); 
      int result = goalsFor - gaolsAgainst ;
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: It's getGoalsFor()  and getGoalsAgainst() . Especially if a newby is asking these kind of mistakes can become confusing for the asker ;)

Answer (score -1):

You want to capture the 2 values, then return the difference of those, not directly subtract the two methods. Maybe something like:

```
public static int totalGoals(int goalsFor, int goalsAgainst){
return goalsFor - goalsAgainst;
```

If you want it all in one method.

Comment: why static and why the input variables?